Changing default systemd-resolvd stub listener from 127.0.0.53 to 127.0.0.54?
Currently systemd-resolvd sets 127.0.0.53 as stub listener in /etc/resolv.conf.
I would like this to change to the 127.0.0.54 alternative by default.
How do I do this ?
I am using Debian Bookworm
